# Windows Storage Server 2008 Search

Tags: windows, search

Some of my users are having an issue searching on our file server. For some reason they are not able to search past 2 or 3 levels of a subdirectory on the server from their local machine.

For example, If they are trying to find a file in z:\one\two\three\four and they are searching from the root, z:\ they will not find it however if they are searching from z:\one\two\three they will find files within the four folder. I do not have this problem on my machine. We are all on Windows 7 and the Server is a Microsoft Windows Storage Server 2008 Standard. I have the File Server role enabled as well as Windows Search Service Role Service enabled.

We are using the built in search bar that is on the top right corner of the windows exploerer window and I cannot tell if there are any default filters that are hindering further search.